# VIA VT6410 BIOS update utility? Gigabyte GA-8I915PL-G motherboard integrated RAID controller

Tags: bios, updates, flashing

I have a Gigabyte GA-8I915PL-G motherboard with a VIA VT6410 RAID controller onboard. I recently purchased a new hard drive that apparently needs the VT6410's BIOS updated in order to have it recognize the drive.

I managed to find the most updated drivers and whatnot from the VIA site, as well as the very most recent BIOS rom file. However, ***FOR THE LIFE OF ME***, I cannot find the utility that actually flashes the damned BIOS! It is absolutely driving me completely crazy.

SO - if any of you have a link to the VIA BIOS Flash utility I will love you forever. and ever. and ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BIOS update for your VT6410 RAID controller will have to be from the manufacturer itself, in this case Gigabyte.

For mobo-integrated RAID controllers, you will need to flash the entire mobo BIOS. It does not work by just downloading from VIA and flashing just the RAID controller BIOS itself.

I suggest you check [www.gigabyte.com](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/download-center.aspx?kw=GA-8I915PL-G&ck=) for the latest updated BIOS, flash it, and give it a whirl.

P.S What exactly is the problem with your new hard drive? Too big for the controller to recognize?